# I have an LACCDB (Microsoft Access Lock File) on a shared Linux drive that I want to delete so that I can amend the database

Tags: linux, microsoft-access, command-line-interface

I'm running Windows myself, but the drive is hosted on a Linux server.

Basically, people map this drive to their Windows machine, open ACCDB files (which they're not supposed to do, we use ACCDE's) and then after they close out, the LACCDB sticks around.

I need to get rid of the LACCDB file. The Windows server has no GUI but I have direct access to it's command line, either by physically going to the server or using Putty.

What commands would I need to type in to navigate to the locked file and then delete it.

Thanks

John

Comment: Have you tried to delete the file? It should be possible as long as the accdb is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the rm command to remove a file from the Linux command line.  So if foo.laccdb is located in /export/Access:

```
rm /export/Access/foo.laccdb
```

One note is the Access lock file can be created without *directly* opening foo.accdb from an Access session.  That could be the case if another Access database file was open which includes a link to a table in foo.accdb.